# How to load .rds file?

Tags: r, ggmap

```
library(ggmap) # -- for geocoding, obtaining city locations
load("gadm36_IND_2_sp.rds")
ind2 = gadm
```

For the above code i am gettig the below error:

Warning message:
“file ‘gadm36_IND_2_sp.rds’ has magic number 'X'
Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated”
Error in load("gadm36_IND_2_sp.rds"): bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
Traceback:

1. load("gadm36_IND_2_sp.rds")

After that below code i am running:

```
# plotting districts of a State, in this case West Bengal
wb2 = (ind2[ind2$NAME_1=="West Bengal",])

nam = c("Purulia","Bankura","Midnapur")
pos = geocode(nam)
tlat = pos$lat+0.05    # -- the city name will be above the marker
cities = data.frame(nam, pos$lon,pos$lat,tlat)
names(cities)[2] = "lon"
names(cities)[3] = "lat"


text1 = list("panel.text", cities$lon, cities$tlat, cities$nam,col="red", cex = 0.75)
mark1 = list("panel.points", cities$lon, cities$lat, col="blue")
text2 = list("panel.text",87.0,26.0,"GADM map", col = "dark green", cex = 1.2)
spplot(wb2, "NAME_1",
sp.layout=list(text1,mark1, text2),
main="West Bengal Districts",
colorkey=FALSE, scales=list(draw=TRUE))
```

Comment: It's probably loaded with `readRDS` function: `gad = readRDS('gadm36_IND_2_sp.rds')`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`readRDS()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readRDS.html) instead of `load()` (which is used with .Rda files):

```
readRDS("gadm36_IND_2_sp.rds")
```

or use `readr` package with [`readr::read_rds()`](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_rds.html), which is basically the same (it's a wrapper for the above):

```
library(readr)
read_rds("gadm36_IND_2_sp.rds")
```

Comment: @R.R.P Maybe try to select menu `Runtime - Factory reset runtime`, make sure you have file `gadm36_IND_2_sp.rds` available in the filesystem (i.e. run `dir()` and check you are on the correct place in the filesystem). Then run the cell with `readRDS()`. If that works, you can run the rest of your code in the next cell.

Comment: Google's Terms of Service: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/.

Please cite ggmap if you use it! See citation("ggmap") for details.
I am getting this.Though late it stops after 2hours without any error.But ind2 = gadm .ind2 object is not defined is shown as output for the next piece of code.